# what does it mean zlib/libpng license ? in short can i use it in my commercial application?

Tags: licensing

i have library that is licensed under zlib/libpng and i what to use it in my commercial application? 
without open my application source , can i ?
i will dynamically link to it

Comment: SO interface is a bit confusing regarding answering questions. I had the problem at the very beginning. A reminder should be implemented.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes** we can!

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/zlib-license.php

> This software is provided 'as-is',
>   without any express or implied
>   warranty. In no event will the authors
>   be held liable for any damages arising
>   from the use of this software.
>
> **Permission is granted** to anyone to use
>   this software for any purpose,
>   **including commercial applications**, and
>   to alter it and redistribute it
>   freely, subject to the following
>   restrictions:
>
> 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
>      claim that you wrote the original
>      software. If you use this software in
>      a product, an acknowledgment in the
>      product documentation would be
>      appreciated but is not required.
> 2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not
>      be misrepresented as being the
>      original software.
> 3. **This notice may not be removed** or altered from any source distribution.